# How to update list of entities in Room

Tags: java, android, android-room

I have API request which gives me a list of entities. I want to update my database by adding(updating) items and deleting the missing ones (which are not included in the response, but included in database). I'm adding and updating data by `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)`. I know, that i can delete missing items manually, by checking each item individually, but can't figure out is there any kind of Room-related solutions for this case.

Comment: Ideally, you track the changes in the UI layer, so that you wind up with separate rosters of what needs to be changed and what needs to be removed, without having to resort to checking the items individually. Room does not have "synchronize this table against this `List` of entities" functionality, AFAIK.

Comment: when you get success response clear all Records in Room Database and add record again in database and get All record form the database and use diff utils for reload recyclerview.

Comment: Thanks guys, but that solutions are workarounds. But I just want to know is there any way of solving this case with  "synchronize this table against this List of entities" like said @CommonsWare, and i guess there is no way so thank you for trying to help.